# Angular doesn't render second <ng-content></ng-content>

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I am trying to build a 'SmartLinkComponent' that can distinguish between internal and external links and at the same time, can wrap any html content in  tag. I came up with the following solution (smart-link.component.html):

```
<a *ngIf="!isInternal" [href]="link" target="_blank" [title]="title">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>

<a *ngIf="isInternal" [routerLink]="link" [title]="title">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>
```

The logic for resolving `isInternal` variable works flawlessly so I am not including the code here.

The problem is that this code only works for the first  that occurs in the layout. Code posted above only renders links that are `!isInternal`. When I swap the code like this:

```
<a *ngIf="isInternal" [routerLink]="link" [title]="title">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>

<a *ngIf="!isInternal" [href]="link" target="_blank" [title]="title">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>
```

then angular only renders `<ng-content></ng-content>` for internal links. 
It even seems like `<ng-content></ng-content>` can be used only once in the layout when it doesn't have any associated `select` directive with it but I couldn't find any documentation regarding this. However, the `*ngIf` conditions here are mutually exclusive, so I am really not sure what's the issue.

Edit: here's (anonymized) code for smart-link.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-smart-link',
    templateUrl: './smart-link.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./smart-link.component.scss']
})
export class SmartLinkComponent implements OnInit {
    isInternal: boolean = true;
    @Input("href") originalLink: string;
    @Input() title: string;

    link: string;


    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.originalLink) {
            console.log('original link', this.originalLink);
            if (some rules) {
                this.isInternal = true;
                this.link = // transform link
            } else {
                this.isInternal = false;
                this.link = this.originalLink;
            }
        }
        console.log('evaluating link', this.originalLink, ' as internal ', this.isInternal, this.link);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are performing multi-content projection, then you need to specify select for atleast one of the them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Shikha mentioned in the comment, it's not possible to use several ng-content elements without specifying the 'select' directive. Using this response from angular GitHub repository https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24567 I was able to fix the solution to only include ng-container once as follows:

```
<a *ngIf="link && !isInternal" [href]="link" target="_blank" [title]="title">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="linkTemplate"></ng-container>
</a>

<a *ngIf="link && isInternal" [routerLink]="link" [title]="title">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="linkTemplate"></ng-container>
</a>

<ng-template #linkTemplate>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```